# Wordpress add_filter('the_content not working properly

Tags: wordpress, post

```
 add_filter('the_content','filter_trendland_content',99999);

//create a the function to get the content of the page by using the hook the_content
function filter_trendland_content($content) {

    $content = "Blank content";
    return $content;

}
```

I tried using the above filter but it works in page and not in post.Is there any changes to be made in other pages of what shall i do this filter to work for posts.It displays the text "Blank Content" but with the post data.please help.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. I already have apply your code in my WordPress environment and works fine !

Comment: its working fine in about page but not any post page

Comment: You may need [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), running this filter like this will affect the admin side too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use the `get_the_content()` function inside your post template file. Replace it with `the_content()` method.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of why this change is necessary and solves the problem in question.